# Does CSS grid suppress margin collapse inside grid items?

Tags: css, css-grid, margin

I understand that a CSS grid element suppresses margin collapse *between* child grid items that are adjacent (adjacent siblings).

But what I think I'm seeing is that a grid element also seems to suppress margin collapse *within* a single grid item, by suppressing margin collapse between that item and that item's own children (parent-descendant margin collapse).

Is that what's going on? Is that what's supposed to happen?

You can see it in a snippet like this:

```css
main {  
  display: grid; 
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

section {
  margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>X</div>
    <div>Y</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

As you can see if you run this snippet, there is 25 px of space between X and Y. This is because the X's 25px margin-bottom is collapsing with its adjacent sibling Y's 25px margin-top, as expected.

But there is 50 px of space between the X content area (outlined in blue) and the top of the grid item content area (outlined in green). This seems to be because the X `div`'s 25px margin-top is *adding and not collapsing* with the `section`'s 25px margin-top. This is what I find confusing.

If you switch main to `display:block`, then you get the normal collapse behavior, where the margin-top of `div` and of `section` collapse together. They also collapse with the margin-top of `main` itself, so that marginal space extends outside `main`'s content area (outlined in green).

I don't understand why this is happening and can't see what in the spec would imply that a grid should affect collapse behavior *within* a grid item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specificaton](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-item-display):

> A grid item establishes **an independent formatting context** for its contents. However, grid items are grid-level boxes, not block-level boxes: they participate in their container’s grid formatting context, not in a block formatting context.

and

> Margins of elements that establish new **block formatting contexts** (such as floats and elements with 'overflow' other than 'visible') do not collapse with their in-flow children.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)</sup>

So margin *inside* a grid item cannot collapse with the margin of the grid item that are *outside*

You can have margin collapsing *inside* the grid if all the concerned margin are *inside*

```css
main {
  display: grid;
}

section {
  margin: 25px 0;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

div {
  margin: 25px 0;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <div>X</div>
    <div>X</div>
  </section>
</main>
```

As you can see, we only have `25px` between the two divs inside the grid item

Comment: Thank you for this answer, illustrating the snippet tool, and the careful citation of the spec, which I will study more closely! However, I think your example also shows the thing that puzzles me, which is that parent-descendent margin collapse is *not* happening within the grid item. I updated my question to make this more clear. But you can see it yourself by adding a green outline to the main element in your snippet. Maybe this is somehow because "they participate in their container’s grid formatting context, not in a block formatting context."?

Comment: @algal *which is that parent-descendent margin collapse is not happening within the grid item* --> and this is what I explained. A grid item establish *an independent formatting context*  so there is no more parent-child margin collapsing. The world inside is closed and no more interaction can be done with the outside.

Comment: @algal you have 3 layers. The grid container establish a grid formatting context so nothing from its outside can collapse with its inside. Then grid items that are sibling cannot interact with each other because there is no margin collapsing inside a grid formatting context. Then each grid item create a formating context so nothing inside will collapse with the outside of the grid item

Comment: Thanks for your patience but I'm still confused. :( In the above example the parent-descendent relationship between `section` and `div` is entirely within a single grid item, so it doesn't require interaction with outside of the grid item. You said "You can have margin collapsing inside the grid if all the concerned margin are inside" and the margins of `div` and of `section` are entirely inside a single grid item. So why don't their margins collapse?

Comment: @algal ok so your confusing is in the roles of each item. main = grid container .. section = grid item ... divs = elements inside the grid item

Comment: Ah, I think I see it! As you observed, spec section 8.3.1 points out that "Margins of elements that establish new block formatting contexts ... do not collapse with their in-flow children". Since the `section` element _establishes_ a new block-formatting context, it will *not* collapse with its child `div` -- *even if it and the `div`'s margins are inside the grid item*! But you _will_ see parent-descendent margin collapse between those child `div`s and _their_ children, sine those `div`s do not establish a block context.

Comment: @algal no, section is not inside the grid item, it's the grid item.

Comment: Okay. Let's call it the grid item But the key point here (for me at least) is that you will *not* get parent-descendent margin collapse between the grid item and its children, even if they are both DIVs. But you will get margin collapse between the grid item's children and their children.

Comment: @algal yes, the rules of non collapsing are: grid container will not collapse with grid item. grid items will not collapse between each other, grid item will not collapse with its childs. That's all. All the other combination are out of the CSS grid scope and they will (or will not) collapse considering different rules

Comment: Thank you again for your patience. I have not seen these rules stated so clearly anywhere.